# Ansible when creating an RDS instance: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ansible, rds

I am working on creating an AWS infrastructure based on Ansible. 
I have a playbook which creates an RDS instance. When I run the playbook standalone it executes perfectly & creates RDS instance. However when that playbook is called by another playbook using the

> include: rds.yml

It gives the following error

> TASK: [create mysql RDS instance] ********************************************* 
>   failed: [localhost -> 127.0.0.1] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/rahul/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1424469014.33-157847268952956/rds", line 2419, in 
>       main()
>
> File "/home/rahul/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1424469014.33-157847268952956/rds", line 468, in main
>       params["vpc_security_groups"] = vpc_security_groups.split(',')
>   AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'
>
> FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

The ansible playbook for RDS which I am using is as follows

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
   - ../group_vars/dev_vpc
   - ../group_vars/dev_sg
   - ../hosts_vars/ec2_info
   - ../hosts_vars/rds_info
  vars:
    instance_type: db.m1.medium
    db_engine: MySQL
    engine_version: 5.6.19a
    subnet: dev-subnet-group
    iops: 1000
    db_name: dev_rds
  tasks:
   - name: Creating RDS subnet group
     local_action:
     module: rds_subnet_group
     state: present
     name: "{{ subnet }}"
     region: "{{ region }}"
     description: Subnet Group for RDS instance
     subnets:
       - "{{ PrivateSubnetA }}"
       - "{{ PrivateSubnetB }}"
 - name: create mysql RDS instance
   local_action:
     module: rds
     command: create
     instance_name: dev-rds
     region: "{{ region }}"
     size: 100
     instance_type: "{{ instance_type }}"
     db_engine: "{{ db_engine }}"
     engine_version: "{{ engine_version }}"
     subnet: "{{ subnet }}"
     multi_zone: yes
     db_name: "{{ db_name }}"
     username: "{{ username }}"
     password: "{{ pass }}"
     vpc_security_groups: "{{ sg_mysql  }}"
     iops: "{{ iops }}"
```

I have searched a lot on the internet and wasn't able to find a correct answer. Can anyone point out my mistake. Thank you

Comment: You have vpc_security_groups set to "{{ sg_mysql  }}" in the call to the rds module.  That seems to be the source of the error you posted, however nowhere in your code do I see what you're setting sg_mysql to.  Are you sure sg_mysql is set? What are you setting it to?

Comment: @BruceP the {{ sg_mysql }} parameters are set in the dev_sg vars_file , which is getting included as part of playbook run. Also the entire playbook executes fine when done individually. However if I call this file from another playbok it throws an error.

Comment: Are you sure "another" playbook is not overwriting sg_mysql variable?

Comment: So what is sg_mysql being set to?  If necessary verify what it's set to by adding the task "debug: var=sg_mysql".

Comment: ok: [localhost] => {
    "var": {
        "sg_mysql": {
            "changed": false,
            "group_id": "sg-d73012b2",
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": "",
                "module_name": "ec2_group"
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: vpc_security_groups: "{{ sg_mysql.group_id  }}"
fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by replacing

vpc_security_groups: "{{ sg_mysql  }}"

with

vpc_security_groups: "{{ sg_mysql.group_id  }}"

the problem was due to wrong data being passed to module.